# How to shutdown the computer from SLiM when root login is disabled?

Tags: debian, shutdown, login-manager

I installed the SLiM login manager on Debian Wheezy and disabled the root account's ability to login, as described in [this Debian Wiki article](https://wiki.debian.org/Root), so `sudo <command>` must be used to run anything as root.

When I try to shutdown the system from SLiM, by following the instructions in the [SLiM manual](http://slim.berlios.de/manual.php), i.e. typing "halt" as the username, then a password, SLiM does not shutdown. `/var/logs/slim.logs` reports this error:

```
slim: pam_authentication(): Authentication failure
```

- This problem does not appear when Debian is configured to allow root to login.

How can I shutdown the computer from SLiM when root login is disabled?

Comment: Is `halt` command available in system ?

Comment: According to the config file, when "halt" is typed into SLiM, it should call "/sbin/shutdown -h now".

Comment: Note, the system is setup to not allow root to login using `su`, but to allow `sudo`. Could this be interfering with SLiM trying to shutdown the computer?

Comment: most likely disabling root-login is the problem here. `slim` needs a way to verify that you typed the correct root password.

Comment: There is a logfile `/var/log/slim.log` what does it say in there ?

Comment: After typing `halt` and a password, `/var/log/slim.log` has a line saying "slim: pam_authentication(): Authentication failure".

Answer (score 1):

You may want to tell SLiM to call `sudo shutdown -h now` and `sudo` to not ask password for that command ( `your_user ALL=(ALL) ALL, NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown` in your `/etc/sudoers`).

You can also switch `tty` by typing `CTRL + ALT + Fx` (where x is the `tty` you want to switch to), login in and shutdown the computer.

Comment: urgh, why would you want to allow *everybody* to shutdown the system? the default in slim is to only allow people who know the root-password to do that!

Comment: I cannot figure out the meaning of your answer. Have you noticed that the user has denied users to log in as root?
He relies on sudo to get/give programs higher privileges when needed, e.g. to shutdown the system.
Also only allowed users can use sudo.

Comment: i was missing the `you_user` part in your answer and assumed you were granting `*` (all users) the permission to shutdown without password.

Comment: nevertheless this doesn't solve the problem: the OP wants to allow the login-manager to shutdown (within the login screen), rather than login as a given user and then shutdown (which is a completely different task)

Comment: I don't think it's possible then.

Answer (score 1):

unsecure, but works

```
# chmod u+s /sbin/shutdown

$ shutdown -h now
```